# Regex doesnt work when I use $

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, special-characters

```
var x = '#google';    // or '@google' or '%google'
var pattern = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + x);
var result = txt.replace(pattern, '$1' + 'MyNewWord');
```

this code works fine to replace  #google

if I use & or @  instead of # it works fine

only it doesn't work when I use $ instead of # so the following code doesn't work properly

```
var x = '$google';   
var pattern = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + x);
var result = txt.replace(pattern, '$1' + 'MyNewWord');
```

ps I used new RegEXP because x will be user input.

Comment: in regex `$` represent end of string

Comment: `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions.  Escape it correctly and you should be fine.

Comment: Btw, `$1' + 'MyNewWord'` is the same as `$1MyNewWord`, tokens can be interpolated in strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` is a special character in a RegExp so you need to escape it:

```
var x = '\\$google';
var pattern = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + x);
```